# Getting multiple image of same Title

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, taxonomy

Taxonomy image
[image: Taxonomy image]

page image
[image: page image]

Here, I have categorized my page with different page. In that, I categorized with taxonomy and slug. All the title have different taxonomy as shown in the image. But here I am getting multiple image because it have multiple taxonomy.
So, I just want 8 images as the `Business theme` are as shown in images and have to display as per the taxonomy.
As you can see the taxonomy count that is `4`,`4` and `5`, So I am getting record like that, but I want to get record as per `Business theme`, as they are eight but as per taxonomy.

Here what I have tried:

```
<div class="portfolio-items">
                <?php
                $terms = get_terms('portfolio_cat');

                foreach($terms as $row)
                {
                    $args = array('post_type' => 'portfolio','tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array( $row->slug ),
                            )
                        ));

                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    $i=1;
                    ?>

                    <div class="portfolio-item <?php echo $row->slug; ?> col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">

                        <div class="recent-work-wrap">

                            <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                            <?php $large_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' ); ?>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                    <h3><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                    <?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>
                                    <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
                                    <a class="preview" href="<?php echo $large_url; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                    <?php
                        // End of the loop.
                    $i++;   
                    endwhile;
                    endif;
                    WP_Reset_Query();
                }
            ?>

                </div>
```

Comment: what you exactly want??I am not able to understand...

Comment: @Abbas: `Business theme` have the `featured image` and as you can see that there are 8 record of `Business theme`, so I want to fetch 8 `featured image` but as per `taxonomy`. You can read last three lines for more understanding.

Comment: As the `taxonomy` have total 13 count in `taxonomy image`, I am getting 13 images but as I have 8 `Business theme`, I want to fetch only 8 images but as per taxonomy of `page image`.